# PAPI (performance application programming) not working properly?

Tags: c, performance, performancecounter, papi

I downloaded version 4.4 off the site, built it in my own directory and tried writing a small main which kept giving me that num_counters was zero. I then looked at ctests and picked hwinfo.c, and ripped out some of the code from it (and testlib) and threw it into a small main that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <papi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int retval, i, j;
    const PAPI_hw_info_t *hwinfo = NULL;
    const PAPI_mh_info_t *mh;


    retval = PAPI_library_init( PAPI_VER_CURRENT );
    if ( retval != PAPI_VER_CURRENT )
        cerr << "Failed at line " << __LINE__ << endl;

    retval =
        papi_print_header
        ( "Test case hwinfo.c: Check output of PAPI_get_hardware_info.\n",
          &hwinfo );
    if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
        cerr << "Failed at line " << __LINE__ << endl;
}
```

I built this using the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/home/pchan/rabbit/papi/include /home/pchan/rabbit/papi/lib/libpapi.a
```

and ran it with:

```
./a.out
```

only to witness this output:

Test case hwinfo.c: Check output of PAPI_get_hardware_info.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAPI Version             : 4.4.0.0
Vendor string and code   :  (0)
Model string and code    :  (0)
CPU Revision             : 0.000000
CPU Megahertz            : 0.000000
CPU Clock Megahertz      : 0
CPUs per Node            : 0
Total CPUs               : 0
Number Hardware Counters : 0
Max Multiplex Counters   : 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm a little lost on what is going on and why this isn't working...what is this symptomatic of and what can I try to fix it? My processor is Intel Xeon X5760 and my uname -a says:

```
Linux chanbox 2.6.18-308.4.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 28 01:54:56 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score -1):

try "papi_avail -a" to know what is supported on your PC.